# What is a SOAP JavaScript proxy?

Tags: javascript

I would like to call a WSDL web service from JavaScript using https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap.

When I use the above library, it run into CORS problems, and the documentation says if i install some kind of proxy I can override that problem. My question is what is a proxy and how does it work? My intention is to call Escapia (https://beta.escapia.com) using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proxy would reside on your server, the same server you serve your pages from.

jQuery would send a request to your proxy (e.g., your server). The proxy would make the request to the WSDL web service and pass it back to your jQuery. This avoids the cross-site issue.

Comment: i can load a remote xml using yql something like this:http://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2013/07/17/fetching-cross-domain-xml-in-javascript-simple-solution/ in the same way can i use any service like that to sop request ? using yql means using proxy service ? if so can you suggest god service that help me to request a sop service from jquery

Comment: @sudeepcv Yahoo is acting as the proxy in that example.